# How do I add items to a list inside a 'for' loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, append

I have following code which does not work (list_of_d is defined previously as an empty list)

```
for item in [3,5]:
    list_of_d.append(i for i in range(item, 15, item))
```

This seems to only return the last iteration.
The result I want is

```
[3,6,9,12,5,10]
```

Thanks

Comment: *"This seems to only return the last iteration"*. That cannot be true. You might be getting a list of generators.

Comment: Yes, I'm getting [<generator object <genexpr> at 0x038CBE98>, <generator object <genexpr> at 0x0075F6F0>] Don't know what this means

Answer (score 0):

*"This seems to only return the last iteration"*. That cannot be true. You might be getting a list of generators.

Instead you have to do a list comprehension and `extend` on list:

```
list_of_d = []

for item in [3,5]:
    list_of_d.extend([i for i in range(item, 15, item)])

print(list_of_d)
```

Comment: That does work but the generators are still in the list. Do I have to remove those after? What are they?

Comment: @ThanosDodd, This outputs in your expected output. Please copy the above code as such and try.

Comment: I removed the brackets from the above and the generators went. Cheers

Comment: Which brackets?

Comment: the [ ] brackets in [i for i in range(item, 15, item)]

Comment: It should work with brackets as well! Which version of Python do you use?

Comment: Latest I assume, downloaded 2 weeks ago. It works with the brackets too. What I meant was, was that the generators disappeared when not using brackets